# Derivation of elastic energy per unit volume

Tags: elasticity, continuum-mechanics

So I basically asked this question a little while back and didn't get much help, but I really need help, so I'm coming back and asking again.

Looking at the section on [Continuum Systems](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elastic_energy#Continuum_systems) on the wikipedia page for elastic energy, the first equation in the section is

$$ U = \frac{1}{2}C_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl} $$

And remember, this is in Einstein notation, so U is really a sum over $i,j,k,l$.

I CANNOT figure out how to derive this equation. Literally everywhere I go, this relation is just HANDED out with either no justification at all or a derivation so notationally byzantine I cannot read it.

If someone knowledgeable enough/smarter than me could PLEASE give me a quick but clear derivation of U from the elastic strain tensor I would REALLY, REALLY appreciate it.

Thank you.

Comment: I think both approaches (basically a definition vs. a byzantine "derivation") are worthwhile. The definition writes down the most general form (?) of volume element energy in a linear(ized) system, the derivations are probably just the three dimensional analogs to the derivation of the mechanical energy of a spring. I can't think of something in-between that isn't just a handwaving version of either.

Comment: Hooke's law in three dimensions gives $\sigma_{ij}=c_{ijkl}\epsilon_{kl}$, so that equation you quote is the exact same as saying $U=1/2\sigma_{ij}\epsilon_{kl}$. From what I can tell, to get that equation texts will find the energy density due to pure normal stress and then pure shear stress and then simply combine them. There are no cross terms since work is only done along the direction of the force.

Answer (score 2):

I needed this too so I worked out a different derivation that works for shear as well.

Consider a block of material with side legths $2\delta x$, $2\delta y$, and $2\delta z$.
We deform it from a strain state of $\varepsilon_{ij}=0$ to $\varepsilon_{ij}=\varepsilon_{ij}^0$ linearly.
That is,
$$
\varepsilon = t\,\varepsilon_{ij}^0
$$
A point $\vec x^0$ travels along
$$
  x_i = t\,\varepsilon_{ij}^0 x_j^0 + tu_i
$$
Where $u_i$ is a rigid body displacement (this will not contribute).
The traction on a surface is
$$
T_i = n_j\sigma_{ij} = tn_jC_{ijkl}\varepsilon_{kl}^0.
$$
The work done on the top surface is
$$
W _{z}
  = \int_{-\delta x}^{\delta x}\int_{-\delta y}^{\delta y}
   \int_0^1
   T_i\frac{dx_i}{dt}
   \,dt \, dx \,dx
$$
If you sub it all in and work out the integrals then you'll find that
$$
W_z = 2C_{i3kl}\varepsilon_{kl}^0 (\varepsilon_{i3}^0\,\delta x\,\delta y\,\delta z-2u_i \,\delta x\,\delta y).
$$
Do the same for the other 5 surfaces, add them together and you get the total work done is
$$
W = 4C_{ijkl}\varepsilon_{kl}^0 \varepsilon_{ij}^0\,\delta x\,\delta y\,\delta z
$$
Which you then divide by the volume of $8\,\delta x\, \delta y\,\delta z$ to obtain the average energy put into your block.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a derivation in one dimension for squashing by $\Delta x$ a block of material of dimensions $x,y,z$.  The block of material in this direction is like a spring (Force=SpringConstant x Distance).  The potential energy stored in a spring with spring constant k is:
$$
[Joules]=[{{Newtons}\over {meters}}][meters]^2
$$
$$
V={1\over 2}k(\Delta x)^2
$$
$$
{V\over x}={1\over 2}kx({{\Delta x} \over x})^2
$$
$$
{V\over xyz}={1\over 2}({{kx}\over {yz}})({{\Delta x} \over x})^2
$$
$$
U={1\over 2}C_{1111}\epsilon_{11}\epsilon_{11}
$$
$$
[{{Joules}\over {meters^3}}]=[{{Force_x}\over {meters^2}}][Frac][Frac]
$$
The equation
$$
U={1\over 2}C_{ijkl}\epsilon_{ij}\epsilon_{kl}
$$
is covarient (invariant under rotation).  Since it was demonstrated true in one frame, it is therefore true in all frames.

Comment: Can you modify it to include shearing? It works fine for an isotropic material as you can consider it in each of the principle strains, but what about a weird material that produces shear stress from axial strains and the like?

Comment: @Cramer By demonstrating this rotationally invariant equation is true in the special frame where $\epsilon$ is diagonal (principle strains), and assuming C and $\epsilon$ transform like tensors under rotation,  then the equation is true in all frames.  I don't think C has to be the special isotropic tensor $C_{ijkl} = K (\delta_{ij}\, \delta_{kl}) +\mu\, (\delta_{ik}\delta_{jl}+\delta_{il}\delta_{jk}-\frac{2}{3}\, \delta_{ij}\,\delta_{kl})$ where K, $\mu$ are the bulk, shear moduli.  C just has to transform like a tensor and could be for the weird material you propose.

Comment: Where is the account for shear stress though? What if $C_{1112}$ is non-zero? When compressing in the $x$ direction shearing will be induced which is not accounted for in the above calculations. Rotating away from a pure $x$ deformation I don't believe will help find that contribution. Regardless, I've found a solution I'm happy with. Both are here and people can decide for themselves which will suffice for them.